# memoir without chapters

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

Is it possible to use memoir without having chapters?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use the `article` option to simulate an article class. You don't need to call `\chapter`, though it's still possible, having a `\section`-like effect: similar heading, no page break.
If this option has been set, numbering of figures, tables etc. is continuous.

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,article,oneside]{memoir}
```

Comment: Thanks!  One further question:  When I do that, my sections are still numbered 0.1, 0.2, etc.  How do I make these 1., 2., etc.?

Comment: By `\counterwithout{section}{chapter}`.

Comment: I put `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}` and `\setcounter\secnumdepth{1}` I also put the option `openany` but this might be redundant?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: Does the `[article]` option still have any effects with the `\counterwithout` command?