# ToC in memoir without chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I use the memoir class in writing an abstract and use only sections and subsections and got an empty table of contents. How do I fix this?
I did like here:
[memoir without chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7325/memoir-without-chapters)
but it didn't help.

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,article,oneside,openany]{memoir}

% --------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=25mm,right=10mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,nofoot,nomarginpar}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{12.3pt}
%%% Колонтитулы %%%
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{\thepage}{}
\pagestyle{plain}
%------------------------------
\usepackage[final]{microtype} % межсимовольный рендеринг, борящийся с оверфуллами

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{STIX2Text}[
    Path           = ./fonts/STIXv2.0.2/ ,
    UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
    BoldFont       = *-Bold ,
    ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ]

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math}[
    Path = ./fonts/STIXv2.0.2/ ]

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[labelsep=period,labelfont=bf,figurename={Рис.},figurewithin=none]{caption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\OnehalfSpacing* %полуторный интервал для всего текста
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\large {\textbf{Содержание}}} %%% переименовали оглавление в memoir на содержание
% --------------------------------------------------------
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\input{title}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\input{introduction}
\input{theory}
\input{methods}
\input{high_frequency}
\input{conclusion}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make sure your example is self contained, you input stuff we don't have access to

Comment: There is a good chance that the line `\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\large {\textbf{Содержание}}}` is at fault here since you ask `\tableofcontents` to just print a word. What you want is to do `\renewcommand{\contentsname{Содержание}}`

Comment: just for example:
https://ru.overleaf.com/6739953172hwfccyttkfny

Comment: I edit by your @KersouMan  example and the compiler returned an error: `command \contentsname{Содержание} undefined.`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it's `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Содержание}` you want, wrong braces placement.

Comment: Thank you, one less problem. So, what about ToC without chapters? Who has ideas?

Comment: The problem was solved using this code:
`\newcommand{\huection}[1]{%
    \section*{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
}

\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\newcommand{\subhuection}[1]{%
    \subsection*{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
}`
I replaced all` \section` with `\huection` and all `\subsection` with `\subhuection`
That old soviet school, yeah baby!

Comment: We can't quite tell what you did because you didn't use TeX.SE formatting.  Regardless, it's better to post your answer as an answer, so that it can be voted on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your self answer correctly, you just want to use nu-numbered sections and still have their title show up in the TOC?

That is easy with `memoir`

```
\setsecnumdepth{none}
\maxsecnumdepth{none} % due to \mainmatter
```

and then use `\section` and friends as normal.

Comment: Thank you for your response, simple and working code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `memoir` with only `section` and below then use it with the `article` option, whereby `\chapter` is set at `\section`, `\section` is set as `\subsection`, etc.

Thank you for your MWE which didn't work for me as I didn't have the font you were using. Here is a very stripped down version of your MWE which does not typeset chapters and gives a ToC.

```
% memtocprob.tex SE 565843
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,article,oneside,openany]{memoir}

%\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\begin{document}

%\input{title}

\newpage
\tableofcontents*
\newpage

%\section{Introduction} %\input{introduction}
\chapter{Introduction}
Introductory text.
\section{Stuff}
More text.
%\input{theory}
%\input{methods}
%\input{high_frequency}
%\input{conclusion}
\end{document}
```

However, if you uncomment the `\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}` then no ToC is produced. The problem lies in the use of the `babel` package which I have never used.

Comment: It remains a mystery to me why such a powerful the memoir class is not optimized for working with babel?

Comment: @user226232 we cannot control what `babel` and its languages does or when users misuse macros that clearly should only contain text. I have no issues with Peters example on an up to date TL20 once russian fonts have been generated.

Comment: @PeterWilson what does your system do when that babel line is used? After mine finished generating russian bitmap fonts I have a toc with a russian header and two items written in English

Comment: thank you for your answer, I made a code based on your example.

Comment: @daleif I have emailed you seperately about this, but essentially I don't have the russian font.

Comment: I have the full fully up to date tl2020 there it pdflatex just started generating the fonts automatically. I don't remember if lmodern contrains them

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by the method suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4002358

```
\newcommand{\huection}[1]{%
    \section*{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
}

\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\newcommand{\subhuection}[1]{%
    \subsection*{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
}
```

I replaced all `\section` with `\huection` and all `\subsection` with `\subhuection`.

Comment: So you only have un-numbered sections? Then we can do something easier, `\setsecnumdepth{none}\maxsecnumdepth{none}` and then you can just use `\section` as normal. It is not easy to figure out your intensions from your example when you don't show us code you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need newcommands, nor the `\counterwithout{section}{chapter}` tricks.

Using  the `article` option `\chapters` are like section, so you only have to replace `\section` by `\chapter` and `\subsection` by `\section` and so on with sublevel, if thre are some.

Note that starred versions of sectioning commands  (\chapter*, \sections*, etc.) are designed to (1) be unnumbered and (2) do dot  appear in the ToC.

If you want only not numbered headers modify `secnumdepth` (as daleif pointed, in memoir you can use \setsecnumdepth and \maxsecnumdepth for this, see section 6.3 of the memoir's manual) and to show these in the ToC setting `tocdepth` properly: Example using the standard \setcounter:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\chapter{foo} The (fake) section
\section{bah} The (fake) subsection
\end{document}
```

In case that you want mix numbered and unnumbered chapters and sections in the ToC, use the starred and not starred versions and \addcontentsline as needed. Example:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\chapter{foo} The (fake) section
\section{bah} The (fake) subsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{baz}
\chapter*{baz} Another  (fake) section
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{buf}
\section*{buf} Another  (fake) subsection
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this code really works.